# Surface of revolution between two circles

Tags: integration, surface-integrals

I want to compute the surface of revolution between thoose two circles $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$. I assume that the radius of the circles follow a well known law $x(y)$.

What I don't understand is that in my book, they say that an infinitesimal surface is : $2 \pi r(y) ds$ with $ds=\sqrt{dx^2+dy^2}$.

But I would choose $2 \pi r(y) dy$. Indeed if I want to compute the volume I would write : $ \pi r^2(y) dy$, so why should I take $ds$ for the surface and $dy$ for the volume, I don't understand.

(I know that the fact I take $dy$ for the volume is not a justification to take $dy$ for the surface but what I want to know is...how can I know which differential element is the good one ???).

How to be sure of the good differential element to take ?

[image: Surface of revolution to compute]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really comes down to the same reason why you don't just use $dx$ or $dy$
to measure the length of a curve.
Instead, the element of length measurement is $ds = \sqrt{dx^2 + dy^2}$.

Consider the two curves $y = f(x) = 2$ and
$y = g(x) = 2+\sin\left(200\pi x\right)$
from $(x,y) = (0,2)$ to $(x,y) = (1,2).$
For the area between either curve and the $x$ axis, the integrals
$\int_0^1 f(x)\,dx$ and $\int_0^1 g(x)\,dx$ are perfectly correct and
both give the result $2.$
But the *length* of the curve $(x,g(x))$ is clearly much longer than
the length of $(x,f(x))$.
You have to follow the path of the curve in the direction the curve
actually follows, not just in either the $x$ direction or the $y$ direction
alone, to measure the length of the curve.

The reason it *really* comes down to the same reason is that
the area of the shaded surface in your figure is 
$2\pi x$ times the length of the $(x,y)$ curve between the two surfaces,
not $2\pi x$ times the distance between the surfaces.
After all, that surface is generated by taking that particular bit of the curve and sweeping it around the $y$ axis, 
not by taking some vertical line segment and sweeping it around the $y$ axis.

Answer (score 0):

$dA =2 \pi r(y) ds$ makes no sense of consistency of used notation.

With $(x,y)$ notation of axes $ ds =\sqrt{dx^2+dy^2}$  and surface area $ dA = 2 \pi x ds  = 2 \pi x(y) ds, $ and

with $(r,z)$ notation of axes  $ ds =\sqrt{dr^2+dz^2}$ and  surface area $dA =  2 \pi r ds =  2 \pi r(z) ds$